# Initital value Swift UserDefault

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I was wondering if there is a way to set a start value for NSUserDefaults
I would like to have a value in the beginning in a UserDefault and than change it latter and never reset it to the Inital Value unless the App is reinstalled.

I searched the web but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way. It's described in the documentation

> At launch time, an app should register default values for any
>   preferences that it expects to be present and valid. When you request
>   the value of a preference that has never been set, the methods of the
>   `NSUserDefaults` class return default values that are appropriate for
>   the data type. For numerical scalar values, this typically means
>   returning 0, but for strings and other objects it means returning nil.
>   If these standard default values are not appropriate for your app, you
>   can register your own default values using the `registerDefaults:`
>   method. This method places your custom default values in the
>   `NSRegistrationDomain` domain, which causes them to be returned when a
>   preference is not explicitly set.
>
> When calling the `registerDefaults:` method, you must provide a
>   dictionary of all the default values you need to register. Listing 2-1
>   shows an example where an iOS app registers its default values early
>   in the launch cycle. You can register default values at any time, of
>   course, but should always register them before attempting to retrieve
>   any preference values.
>
> ```
> // Listing 2-1
> func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {   
>     // Register the preference defaults early.
>     let appDefaults = ["CacheDataAgressively" : true]
>     NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(appDefaults)
>     // Other initialization... 
> }
> ```

Source : [Accessing Preference Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AccessingPreferenceValues/AccessingPreferenceValues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH3-SW1)